# CDK diff command always displays change in expiry time of API key

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cdk

I'm using the CDK service to generate a CloudFormation template for the AppSync service where authentication used is API Key based.

To note, my API key's validity is 365 days.

The strange thing is that although I don't have any change in CDK code, still whenever I run 'cdk diff' command, it always highlights change in expiry time of the API key as follows:

```
Stack AppSyncStack-dev
Resources
[~] AWS::AppSync::ApiKey GraphqlAPI/devkeyApiKey GraphqlAPIdevkeyApiKey7B654D8E
 └─ [~] Expires
     ├─ [-] 1652178692
     └─ [+] 1652186636
```

After further triage, I've observed that it is always calculating the API key's expiry time by using a time when 'cdk diff' command is run, and correspondingly it extends the expiry time of the key. To explain, in case I run a 'cdk diff' now, than it will have change set with expiry time as present time of next year as I've 365 day's key validity.

**I don't want to change API key's expiry time on each call of 'cdk diff' command.**

Any workaround to achieve it?
OR any way to ignore a specific field (here expiry time of API key) for 'cdk diff' command?

Environment - Java 8, CDK version 1.113.0 in the pom file of maven

Comment: Did you manage to figure this out? I have a similar issue with API Gateway: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74776072/cdk-diff-always-shows-changes-for-api-gateway-deployment