# CDK Diff Always Shows Changes for API Gateway Deployment

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, aws-cdk, infrastructure-as-code

I've built a simple API Gateway proxy to S3 using CDK (with Java).

After deploying the stack, `cdk diff` always reports that there are changes that need to be deployed, despite no changes to the resources in the Java code:

```bash
Resources
[-] AWS::ApiGateway::Deployment apiDeployment149F129425c1eab792837971bc799db7cbb35642 destroy
[+] AWS::ApiGateway::Deployment api/Deployment apiDeployment149F1294513443c293e803fe7996a9d31691b8b7
[~] AWS::ApiGateway::Stage api/DeploymentStage.prod apiDeploymentStageprod896C8101
 └─ [~] DeploymentId
     └─ [~] .Ref:
         ├─ [-] apiDeployment149F129425c1eab792837971bc799db7cbb35642
         └─ [+] apiDeployment149F1294513443c293e803fe7996a9d31691b8b7
```

Any idea how to suppress this? My best guess is that a tag or something else is being generated at synth time that is making CDK think that there's a change, but I haven't been able to track it down.

CDK Version: 2.53.0 (build 7690f43)
Java Version: 17.0.3

Edit: I've added a small project to reproduce the issue here, with steps to reproduce in the README: https://github.com/noelob/cdk_diff_bug_repro

Comment: Please add a minimal code example. Regarding the question - you cannot suppress it.

Comment: Updated my question with a link to a project to repro the issue :)

Answer (score 0):

The logicalId of the deployment is generated based on a hash of the child resources. Looking at your sample code, you seem to be passing a request parameters map which I think is producing an inconsistent hash across invocations of cdk diff.

I had a similar setup and wrapping the request parameters map in a TreeMap seems to have fixed the issue for me (At-least as far as I can tell. Diff has come out empty for the last 10 invocations when previously I used to see spurious diffs every 2-3 invocations). The first invocation of CDK diff after this change may still show a diff but subsequent invocations should be fine.

Comment: Interesting! We've abandoned CDK and moved back to Terraform :) Thanks for taking the time to suggest a solution, hopefully it will be helpful for other folks.